# DidSelectItemAtIndexPath not working with collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I have been struggling with this for a while now. I have a UICollectionView that I am using as a menu. The cells are the options to switch to another page. The menu functions exactly how it should except that when you press a cell, say cell 0, it should pop to the next view. What I am finding is that the cell is registering the touch but when I try and determine which cell was pressed is when it falls apart. I have tried debugging it and to me it looks like indexPath has no value! I am using the didSelectItemAtIndexPath function, no it is not didDeselect (I checked that already from my searches on how to fix this). I will post the code but this one has really stumped me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    NSLog("Pressed Cell")

    if(indexPath == 0)
    {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIndexPath comprises both a section and an item, which you can access as `indexPath.item` and `indexPath.section`.  Assuming you have only one section (so its value is irrelevant), you can change your code to:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    NSLog("Pressed Cell")

    if(indexPath.item == 0)
    {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks that time during the debug it stepped into the if statement. Now I just need to get the other view to pop up. Currently it still does nothing when you press the cell but that is probably not related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure normally call the delegate method but if have add any Gesture to the view. Make sure before you add your gesture recognizers to you're view, make sure the boolean property "cancelTouchesInView" is set to false. This could be because the gesture is recognized so it ignores passing touches to the view causing the cell selection method not to be called. Link to property.

Comment: This is an old thread but sorry the accepted answer was the correct one. I had not realized that indexPath has a section and an item access method, such as indexPath.row and indexPath.section.